# `FIRApp configure` is crashing my app, how do I fix it?

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native

I have this line in my `AppDelegate.m` file: `[FIRApp configure];`

more precisely it looks like this:

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  [FIRApp configure];
```

at the top: `#import <Firebase.h>`

it's definitely breaking here as when I comment it out, rebuild my app, distribute to my device it works fine. it also works fine both ways on the simluator (annoyingly meaning I have to rebuild and distribute every time to test a fix)

I saw the error happening here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/340

I've tried the fix here but to no avail. I have my `GoogleService-Info.plist` in xcode living under my files. I added it by right clicking and clicking "Add file to..."

this file is NOT showing in vs code under my `/ios` app though. is that correct?

how do I fix this now? causing a lot of pain

Comment: Make sure that the file is in your project directory (right click > show in finder will take you to the file's location) _and_ added to your target.

Comment: @Alladinian I've got `GoogleService-Info.plist`  in my root. when I go to file location it shows under `/ios` folder. is that right? also under Target Membership it shows it's selected for the first one (my app). all the other ones are unticked but they are just tests and TVOS which I don't use. is that all correct?

Comment: also why is this working locally on emulator but breaking on my device?

Comment: Just realized that we're talking about a react-native project (for which I have zero experience) so maybe someone more knowledgeable than me can help, but I would expect that if this file is present in the "copy bundle resources" in the build phases it should be working...

Comment: ha no worries. and yeh it's there :'( do you know much about app delegate stuff? I think I'm using Objective c rather than swift. and my ` [FIRApp configure];` is in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method but some people said to put in an override method. do you know much about that?