# FirebaseMessagingError: Invalid registration token provided

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send push notifications to another iOS device using firebase cloud functions but I receive the following error below when attempting to do so:

'FirebaseMessagingError: Invalid registration token provided. Make sure it matches the registration token the client app receives from registering with FCM.'

This is the registration token I am trying to send to 6e04bb35f06e2d981d5603bbd229eeab5ee5649f6af7b4ecc3894be6ad1574d7 which is the same token I have saved in my realtime database:

[image]

Below is my onCreate function:

```
   exports.onMessageCreate = functions.database.ref('/messages/{chatId}/{messageId}').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
      
      const chatId = context.params.chatId;
      const receiverId = chatId.replace(context.auth.uid, '');
      const root = snapshot.ref.root;
        
      return admin.database().ref(`/users/${receiverId}/regToken`).once('value').then(tokenSnap => {
          var regTokenRef = tokenSnap.val();
          
         const payload = {
            notification: {
                title: 'title',
                body: snapshot.val().text,
            }
         };
         
         const options = { priority: "high" };
             
         return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(regTokenRef, payload, options).then(function(response){
             
             console.log("Successfully sent message: ", response);
             console.log(response.results[0].error);
             
         }).catch(function(error) {
             console.log("Error sending message: ", error);
             
         });

      });

  });
```

Do you know what may be causing this error? I am not too sure what I need to check here. Is the format wrong here? Does it need to be in quotes? I have looked at other links but they haven't really helped.

I am importing '@react-native-community/push-notification-ios' to generate the token. I think this may be the problem. I was having issues to use the messaging from firebase. Is this the issue?

Please see below the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method updated in my AppDelegate.m file. Have I placed the below code correctly? When this is added it is causing my app to appear blank when launching the simulator with the FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).? However, when removed my app launches but with still has the FirebaseError.

```
 if ([FIRApp defaultApp] == nil) {
      [FIRApp configure];
 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

@react-native-community/push-notification-ios is not able to generate an FCM token, only APN token: https://github.com/react-native-push-notification-ios/push-notification-ios/issues/117

If you want to use firebase, you need to generate the token from the messaging package of firebase to have a FCM one.

Comment: Thanks. That's where I have a problem. When I try to use firebase.messaging() I get the error 'FirebaseError: Messaging: This browser doesn't support the API's required to use the firebase SDK. (messaging/unsupported-browser).' I think this is due to using Safari on my iPhone. I am now trying to install Babel

Comment: Safari? Push notification are different from web notification

Comment: I'm not sure why I get the error. I want to use push notification

Comment: You don't need any browser to get the token. Just met the messaging getToken at the start of your application

Comment: It's not working. firebase.messaging().getToken gives me the above error. Could it be a problem in my firebase console? I'm very new to this.

Comment: For iOS you need a real device, it doesn't work on a simulator

Comment: Yeah, I'm using my real device not the simulator.

Comment: Are you using expo or a bare react native project?

Comment: Bare react native project

Comment: I saw your other question. Your firebase configuration is for an expo app. you are using the firebase sdk instead of the react-native one: https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage

Comment: Oh dear. Thank you so much. I'm really worried switching will cause so many errors as I tried this before and numerous errors appeared. Plus my tipsi-stripe/stripe wasn't working. But I'll give this a go again

Comment: No unfortunately. I am getting the error 'FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).' after installing @react-native-firebase/app using the link https://rnfirebase.io/. Changing the AppDelegate.m as specified in the link actually causes my app to not load up and appear blank. Removing it will make my app load up but I still get that Firebase Error.

Comment: The line  'if ([FIRApp defaultApp] == nil) { [FIRApp configure]; } ' is causing a problem in my AppDelegate.m file. If added my app appears blank when loading with the FirebaseError above showing in my logs. If removed my app will load up but logging in to my app using package @react-native-firebase/auth causes the same FirebaseError above to appear. Can someone please help here?

Comment: Did you follow the setup guide configuring the GoogleService-Info.plist (iOS) or google-services.json (android)? (https://rnfirebase.io/)

Comment: Yes, for iOS. I downloaded it from my console and added to my project in XCode. Checked the 'copy if needed' and add to target. Should I do it again? Create a new iOS app in the console and download it again?

Comment: I just added a screenshot of my didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method above. Is the code being added correctly? Or could it be iOS 13 being the problem. The iOS platform in my podfile is set to 11

Comment: This seems to be a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66543293/firapp-configure-is-crashing-my-app-how-do-i-fix-it . Can someone please help?

Comment: Do you still have the other package firebase on your project or only react-native-firebase?

Comment: I still have the other firebase package. I didn't think this would cause a problem. Would it?

Comment: It could be. Both packages will try to authenticate with same client to firebase. I don't know if it's possible, probably not. It should not be so difficult for you to migrate all firebase functions to react-native-firebase functions as both use almost the same api.

Comment: If you don't want to migrate to react-native-firebase, you could try to exchange your apn token (generate with react-native-push-notification) with a FCM token using this guide: https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#create_registration_tokens_for_apns_tokens

Comment: Thank you so much! Removing the firebase package worked.